# XML reading code working on my server but not on my client server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

i have written image slider code. It reads all image details from XML file.i have tested it on my server it works fine , but when client is putting it on server images are not loaded seems link XML reading is not  done . can you please help me identify the cause of this ..

Below is the link where client have installed code.

http://gulin.sg/andrea/maple/CoverFlow/webkit.html

```
$.get('photos.xml', function (xml) {
    $('item', xml).each(function (k) {
        frontimg.push($(this).find('frontImg').text());
        stripimg.push($(this).find('stripImg').text());
        frontText.push($(this).find('frontTxt').text());
        fTitle.push($(this).find('title').text());
        fCity.push($(this).find('city').text());
        fYear.push($(this).find('compYear').text());
        fLoc.push($(this).find('loc').text());
        fType.push($(this).find('type').text());
        fRole.push($(this).find('role').text());
        arrBackImg.push($(this).find('backImg').text());
        backText.push($(this).find('backTxt').text());

        frontDiv.push("<h2>" + fTitle[k] + "</h2>" + "<h3>" + fCity[k] + "</h3><hr><h4>YEAR OF COMPLETION</h4>" + fYear[k] + "<hr><h4>LOCATION</h4>" + fLoc[k] + "<hr><h4>PROPERTY TYPE</h4>" + fType[k] + "<hr><h4>MAPLETREE'S TYPE</h4>" + fRole[k]);


        $('#myImageFlow').append('<div id="id' + k + '" alt="div' + k + '" class="sliderImage" width="280" height="425" style="visibility:hidden"> <div class="frontText" id="f' + k + '">' + frontDiv[k] + '</div><div class="borderdiv" id="b' + k + '"></div><div class="borderdiv1" id="bd' + k + '"></div><div class="reflection" id="ref' + k + '"></div>  <div class="overlay" id="o' + k + '"></div></div>');


    });
.........................................


});
```

**Note:**
In console i am not getting any Error and problem.

Comment: @nbrooks that is closed, i only pasted half code ... same code works on my server but on client server it is not working

Answer (score 0):

On the server, are you sure you have the rights to read that XML file?

That might be the problem.